# unexpected end of file when using PHP long tags

Tags: php

I'm getting a weird "unexpected end of file" error with a PHP file after pulling in some changes from a colleague.  By deleting blocks of code selectively, I was able to boil the problem down to two if blocks in the file that are something like this (removed some excess for clarity):

```
<?php if(...) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php print $prefix; ?>specials"><i class="fa fa-tag fa-lg2"></i> <?php print _("Specials"); ?></a></li>
<? } ?>
```

Now, if I change the long-form PHP open tag to a shorttag, the syntax error goes away:

```
<?if(...) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php print $prefix; ?>specials"><i class="fa fa-tag fa-lg2"></i> <?php print _("Specials"); ?></a></li>
<? } ?>
```

I would understand a shorttag causing a problem if shorttags was disabled, but I don't understand how a longtag could be causing this.  Fixing it is easy enough, I just want to know why this is happening in the first place.

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: On the first example 3 line you missed to tiped php
like this:
<?php } ?>

Comment: Version is 5.5.9 (Ubuntu package).

Comment: Changing the PHP open tag for the ending brace to a long tag changes the error to an unexpected closing brace on the brace following this code.

Comment: I tested it now with the 3 line as a long tag and it works fine for me!
Can you post the exact error message please.

Comment: It works fine as is on my colleague's machine as well.  The _ is a function in our system for internationalization.  I would expect that to fail on your system.  The exact error is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/rremer/Projects/blueprint/blueprint/modules/menu.php on line 175 (line 175 is the last line of the file).

Comment: @RichRemer if the error is unexpected end of file and the error is at the last line i would expect that you missed a { or } anywhere. So check your file if you missed any { or }

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the issue was shorttags being disabled.  With the tag disabled, PHP was simply ignoring the if statement and always outputting the content inside the if block, which threw me.  Additionally, I was not aware that with newer versions of PHP, even with shorttags disabled, you can still use the < ?= open tag with an equals sign, which gave me the impression shorttags was enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You should **open and close in the same style** (long or short, whatever You choose).

Long tags:

```
<?php if(..) { ?>
..
<?php } ?>
```

Short tags:

```
<? if(..) { ?>
..
<? } ?>
```